# jQuery slider conflicts with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm handling over someone's work.

He wrote many features with jQuery.

It seems angular js will break the jQuery slider function.

http://jiyubi.com

Any idea or direction to fix the conflict?

## layout-broken version

[image: inline]

## Expected result

[image: inline]

## code

```
        /* ==============================================
            Preload
        =============================================== */
        $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
            $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
            $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
            $(window).scroll();
        })
        /* ==============================================
            Sticky nav
        =============================================== */
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            'use strict';
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
                $('header').addClass("sticky");
            }
            else{
                $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });

        /* ==============================================
            Menu
        =============================================== */
        $('a.open_close').on("click",function() {
            $('.main-menu').toggleClass('show');
            $('.layer').toggleClass('layer-is-visible');
        });
        $('a.show-submenu').on("click",function() {
            $(this).next().toggleClass("show_normal");
        });
        $('a.show-submenu-mega').on("click",function() {
            $(this).next().toggleClass("show_mega");
        });
        if($(window).width() <= 480){
            $('a.open_close').on("click",function() {
            $('.cmn-toggle-switch').removeClass('active')
        });
        }

        $(window).bind('resize load',function(){
        if( $(this).width() < 991 )
        {
        $('.collapse#collapseFilters').removeClass('in');
        $('.collapse#collapseFilters').addClass('out');
        }
        else
        {
        $('.collapse#collapseFilters').removeClass('out');
        $('.collapse#collapseFilters').addClass('in');
        }   
        });
        /* ==============================================
            Overaly mask form + incrementer
        =============================================== */
        $('.expose').on("click",function(e){
            "use strict";
            $(this).css('z-index','2');
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
        });
        $('#overlay').click(function(e){
            "use strict";
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
                $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
            });
        });

        /* ==============================================
            Common
        =============================================== */

        <!-- Tooltip -->    
        $('.tooltip-1').tooltip({html:true});

         //accordion    
        function toggleChevron(e) {
            $(e.target)
                .prev('.panel-heading')
                .find("i.indicator")
                .toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
        }
        $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);


        /* ==============================================
            Animation on scroll
        =============================================== */
        new WOW().init();

        /* ==============================================
            Video modal dialog + Parallax + Scroll to top + Incrementer
        =============================================== */
        $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $('.video').magnificPopup({type:'iframe'}); /* video modal*/
        $('.parallax-window').parallax({}); /* Parallax modal*/
        // Image popups

        $('.magnific-gallery').each(function() {
            $(this).magnificPopup({
                delegate: 'a', 
                type: 'image',
                gallery:{enabled:true}
            });
        }); 

        $('.dropdown-menu').on("click",function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});  /* top drodown prevent close*/

        /* Hamburger icon*/
        var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".cmn-toggle-switch"); 

          for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var toggle = toggles[i];
            toggleHandler(toggle);
          };

          function toggleHandler(toggle) {
            toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              (this.classList.contains("active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("active") : this.classList.add("active");
            });
          };

          /* Scroll to top*/
          $(window).scroll(function() {
                if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                    $('#toTop').fadeIn();   
                } else {
                    $('#toTop').fadeOut();
                }
            });
            $('#toTop').on("click",function() {
                $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},500);
            }); 

            /* Input incrementer*/
            $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>');
            $(".button_inc").on("click", function () {

                var $button = $(this);
                var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

                if ($button.text() == "+") {
                    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
                } else {
                    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
                    if (oldValue > 1) {
                        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                    } else {
                        newVal = 0;
                    }
                }
                $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
            });
        });

        <!-- Cat nav onclick active --> 
        $('ul#cat_nav li a').on('click', function(){
            $('ul#cat_nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        <!-- Map filter onclick active -->  
        $('#map_filter ul li a').on('click', function(){
            $('#map_filter ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        <!-- Input range slider --> 
            $(function () {
                'use strict';
                $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
                    hide_min_max: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 150,
                    from: 30,
                    to: 100,
                    type: 'double',
                    step: 1,
                    prefix: "$",
                    grid: true
                });

            });
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  http://jiyubi.com is a broken link

Comment: sorry its a typo, it should be http://www.jiyubi.com . there's no exception. i guess it's just a tricky confliction .